# Bash shell script confusing command line argument $1 vs awk $11

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a shell script that takes a command line argument (line 1).
Line 2, I want to output the result of awk '{print $11}' and store it into CURRENT_TAG,
however, when it comes across print $11 it automatically tries to plug in the command line argument $1 into that spot. How can I avoid this? Putting a \ before the $ does not work.

Thanks,

```
WORKING_COPY=$1;
CURRENT_TAG=$(ls -l ~/working/svn/$WORKING_COPY/tags/current | grep "current \-\>" | awk '{print $11}');
```

Comment: It is a really bad idea to try to parse the output of `ls`. See [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to see why.  What exactly is in that directory that you want to obtain?

Comment: Superficially, that smacks of a bug in bash - the contents of the awk argument list should not be touched by bash.  The 'no more than 9 arguments' fetish dates back to the Bourne shell - $11 meant ${1}1 in the original Bourne shell.

Answer (score 3):

From your question it seems that current is a symbolic link (or possibly a directory named current containing a symbolic link also named current) and you are trying to figure out what that link references. You can use `readlink` for that.

```
CURRENT_TAG=$(readlink ~/working/svn/$WORKING_COPY/tags/current)
```

OR

```
CURRENT_TAG=$(readlink ~/working/svn/$WORKING_COPY/tags/current/current)
```

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of your script works fine for me. How are you executing your script?

```
markrose@shuttle:/tmp$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

WORKING_COPY=$1;
CURRENT_TAG=$(ls -l /tmp/$1 | awk '{print $1}');
echo $1
echo $CURRENT_TAG
markrose@shuttle:/tmp$ ./test.sh blog.jpeg 
blog.jpeg
-rw-r--r--
markrose@shuttle:/tmp$ bash ./test.sh blog.jpeg
blog.jpeg
-rw-r--r--
```

For what it's worth, my `ls -l` output has only 8 fields, the last being the filename (at least with the filename/path containing no spaces and the LFS environment variable not being set).

Comment: The extra fields likely come from the fact that the file is a symlink like `foo -> bar`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, it *is* a bad idea to use `ls` that way.

Are you saying that the contents of `CURRENT_TAG` becomes the same as that of `WORKING_COPY` with a "1" appended?

Note that escaping `>` makes it special instead of regular. You should do `grep "current ->"`.

Note that AWK can do the selection that you're using `grep` for.

```
awk '/current ->/{print $11}'
```

Comment: Also, use `$NF` instead of `$11`, the intent is clearer and avoids forcing readers of the script to count the fields in the output of `ls -l`.